# Design problem in Microservice architecture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, microservices

In my company we are using `microservices` but till now we were not following `microservice principles`. so in architect review we have been told to replace the same.

We have one service called `CommonService`,so any request comes by client hits this service. This request hits the `database` and create the record and then forward the request to `ManagementService`. Management Service access the same DB and table and update the record created by `CommonService`.(Here Common and Management Both API hitting the same table in database.)
same we have for other 2 services.

```
Common-->DB(Common_MGMT)--Management-->DB(Common_MGMT)
Common-->DB(Common_Sales)--Sales-->DB(Common_Sales)
Common-->DB--HR-->DB
```

So `Common_MGMT` table hit by first 2 service, `Common_Sales` table hit by Common and Sales API ,same for third.
A particular customer will access only one service where it is `Management` , `Sales` or `HR` but he will come through `commonservice`.
[image]

Now We have to follow microservice principle and due to management reasons we can not follow `Database as a service` and also we don't have option to redesign from scratch.

So we have thought to introduce one  `DBservice` which will hit the `database`,so that it is like when new request will come to `Commonservice` then it will access `DBservice` through `REST` and `DB service` will create record in `database`. Then `Management` Service will access `DBservice` and `DBService` will update the same record in `database`. likewise for `sales service` and `HR service`.

Now still I am using same `table` in Database but this time only `DBservice` accessing. AM I following the microservice principle here?

1. Here which approach will be better `Private table per service` or `Schema as a service`? or both will work and I can use either of them?
2. There will be huge `latency` in this approach, can the solution be improved?
3. If `DBService` will fail then it will be single point of failure? can we do something other than creating multiple instances?

Overall can you suggest the solution for original problem? Is the solution we are proposing correct or is there better option?

Any other suggestion most welcome.

[image]

Comment: Title is vague. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: You are not ready for microservices. With that limitations, I suggest to still use monolithic but implement it in modules so that it is somehow compartmentalized i.e. you know where to update when there is enhancement required. Make it as intuitive as possible.

Do not follow microservice just because it is the latest trend.

Comment: Implementing micro services comes with complexity. Having a single database (point of failure) negates any perceived API benefits. Having to manage databases, multiple API's, authorization between everything, not to mention ops and deployments isn't free. If you are doing micro services because you were told to, and not because of a current business need it is not going to solve any problems but introduce more headaches. It is not a silver bullet, it solves scaling, availability and sometimes dev headaches with large teams all trampling in the same repo.

Comment: Seems like senior managers who just care about the buzz word and showcasing working for the sake of it designed this. Common Service is usually a LB or maybe a cross cutting auth server/authorization service using some other auth service, something like that. Why have a service called Common Service create the record and then go to some domain specific service to update the record. What happens if the call fails in MGMt service ? How do you rollback the record ? Does look microservice design for calling it a microservice and cloud ready application !

Comment: Also, I am not against a single DB pattern - everything has its own pros and cons - it's a trade-off and sometimes policies ! If I were to design this - just for the sake of moving to "cloud native architecture" acc to company policy - I would have 3 domain services - mgmt/hr/sales , one LB, one discovery service maybe, and a single DB. If the whole point of Common Service is to share models across without duplicate code - I would write a shared lib to make others happy (personally disagree that this is way - sometimes DRY is not the asnwer)! A simple design and your seniors happy !

Comment: Also, there is no need to DB Service layer (assume this is a separate service) - again don't want duplicate code, create a lib to abstract the data jpa/hib things with your own interface, and use that - but if you see carefully you still are duplicating stuff even after shared libs !! So this is probably satisfying your managers if that is what is required. if not, 3 services, 1 DB, 1 LB(entrypoint), 1 discovery service and probably a common service for authorization/auth abstraction.

Comment: You are asking eight questions within your post. That is a  red flag that your question lacks focus. Also, your question is inviting opinions, and not really on topic for SO. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for clarification. Consider posting  on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead, ensuring that you [meet their guidelines](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Shrutisharma Do not tell people not to downvote. There is nothing wrong with downvoting poor questions, and your question does not follow SO guidelines in several respects. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on improving your question. And you are still asking eight questions within your post. That means that your question lacks focus.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is not simple and straightforward, because there are many parameters involved while breaking a service into microservices. From what I see, you are having multiple services which are communicating with each other frequently but still are having different code bases and on top of that they do access the same database (I am assuming the same schema when you say the same database). Now when you say that you can not do it from scratch then there are very few possible solutions to this problem

1. Instead of updating and hitting the DB every time for the calls in the initial service, why don't you just pass the information to downstream services and let that service do the update if possible (this is still not an ideal solution but it reduces the latency by reducing one DB call)

```
Common-->Pass-Data--Management-->DB(Common_MGMT)
Common-->Pass-Data--Sales-->DB(Common_Sales)
Common-->Pass-Data--HR-->DB
```

2. Do the reverse, instead of landing your API call in Common, why don't you land your API calls in actual services first and then inject Common as a dependency in your services and let that part process other data? (this is still not from scratch but I believe will need considerable amount of work, but still better solution than 1).

Answer (score 1):

Introducing a DBservice as an intermediary between microservices and the database can follow microservice principles.
However, there are aspects to consider.

Private table per service or schema as a service can both work, depending on specific needs. Coordination between services is necessary to avoid conflicts and ensure data consistency.
Using a single database for multiple microservices can cause performance issues.
Database-per-service approach can improve scalability, isolation, and data consistency.
Introducing a DBservice can affect performance due to additional network hops. Caching or optimizing database queries can reduce latency. A load balancer or replicated database cluster can ensure high availability.
Redesigning microservices architecture can improve scalability, and data consistency, and reduce contention.

Event-driven architectures and asynchronous messaging can decouple microservices and improve scalability and fault tolerance.
Containerization and orchestration technologies can simplify the deployment and management of microservices.

Actually considering your scenario specifically, I can think of two other possible solutions for you:

1. Either create Common service as a jar  and import it into your Management, Sales, and HR service and use it from there only
2. Normalization of a table in such a way that Common Service and Management Service etc work on different tables. I am just thinking to divide a table into two parts

Comment: actually we have all 3 types of customers. some of them use all the services, some use exactly one. so to onboard customers we are using commonservice.

Answer (score 1):

So below are the points to keep in mind.

- First, decide how are you segregating your functionalities into services.
- You can segregate based on domain, e.g. customer service, product service etc. Each of this service would have it's own db, and whenever another service needs to deal with anything in this DB, it will go through this microservice.
- You can then build usecase specific services on top of the domain specific services.
- It is really difficult to justify microservice architecture with your DB as a single point of failure.

Please refer to this website for more detailed information on microservices. Since you seem to be just getting started, this is a good starting point.
https://microservices.io/

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach it would be to split the monolith in terms of functional modules with an interface and implementation and then move those modules into standalone services.

The idea is that if one functional module changes, others don't have to be validated as rigorously.

Update#1 -

1. If you want to improve your understanding try this link - https://microservices.io/
2. I have answered in a generic way (was trying to get within the bounty window but now it looks like there is a 1 day grace!). Never the less believe they still hold.

   If you have a single database and that is your primary concern (which makes sense) then backups are your only friend. So you can first think of a replication db before you start thinking about monolith vs microservices. It would be no fun to tell your customers you lost their data because the db server crashed.

   Additionally to improve speed, using RDBMS you can consider sharding concepts (where rows are distributed across multiple servers) in addition to replication. You should ideally be able to manage this within the scope of your definition of 'redesign-from-scratch' limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Calling dbservice via rest api, won't it be like tight coupling and add latency? Can we not do this operation using messaging api? Such that even if dbservice goes down, message can still be processed, once it's up.

Comment: We have scalable and HA DBs too. I dont see how this answer fits the question, of trying to move away from DB to a message queue. With a bad design of "microservices", this answer just adds some more complications(tx management) and components to the issue !

Comment: @PriyakDey So u r saying making rest api calls/ synchronous communication is better than using queues coz it is adding to complexity?

Comment: 1. I don't think its about complexity and good/bad when it comes to sync/async ops. It is about the use case and how to solve it with efficiency and less complexity. With this bad design, a queue does not save the day.
2. There is no point in having a DB service layer at all. Again depends on the use case. After saving models - do I return them immediately - yeah we need a rest-blocking call. It can very simple as - 3 services which takes of mgmt/sales and HR model with a single DB, a Service Reg and LB to start with.

Comment: Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6ow-UemzBc&t=577s) on Microservice Architecture Design. Good watch